# How do I make a directory part of a group?

Tags: permissions, directory, group, chmod, chown

I created a directory and the next step is to make that directory part of a group. 
Is this down with chown? Or another command? This is for my schoolwork. We have gone over permissions and changing file ownership and modigying users. Chown & chmod. But I cant find anything in my notes about making a directory part of a group.
What am i missing?

**Would i use *chown -R group-name directory name/pathway***

The very next questions is changing permissions of "others" which i know how to do.

Comment: When you looked at `chown` did you also look at `chgrp`? If not, I would suggest you do so.

Comment: ok so thank you.  `chgrp group-name directory name`   would be it?

Comment: or should it be recursive?

Answer (score 1):

The way that UNIX operates, everything is a file, including directories. As such, directories can have their user and group changed using chown just like folders.

To change just the top level directory.

```
chown :groupname directory
```

To change the directory and all the sub-files and sub-directories.

```
chown -R :groupname directory
```

If you have any other questions about chown, I would recommend checking out the [chown man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) or taking a look at [this askUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/6727/925802).

Answer (score 0):

Each directory (or file) has **owner**, **group** and **permissions**.

You cannot "make directory part of a group", but you can change directory (or file) group ownership.

The command to change group ownership is **chgrp**:

`chgrp <group> <directory-or-file-name>`

The command **chown** also can be used to change a directory (or file) group membership, where group name is specified together or without owner name.